# Change color on many css elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, colors

How can I change the color on all CSS elements that has the color/background-color #d10044 ?

Comment: It'd be much better to create a class with that background color and then remove the class from all elements that have it and add another one with the new color: $('*').find('.MyBackgroundColor').removeClass('MyBackgroundColor').addClass('MyOtherBackgroundColor');

Comment: @frenchie, I agree with you, but no need for .find(), just use the class as the selector

Comment: @Chimoo: yea, you could also write it like this: $('.MyBackgroundColor').removeClass('MyBackgroundColor').addClass('MyO‌​therBackgroundColor'); In any case, it's much more efficient to change classes than to loop through every element, parse its background color and then change the color!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('*').each(function() {
    if($(this).css("background-color") == "#d10044") {
        // do whatever you need to those elements here
    }
});​​​​
```

It goes through all the elements on the page, though, so that could be rather slow. If you have a way of narrowing the list of possible elements, that would be preferable to the global (`*`) operator.

Comment: It seems, you can only search for rgb(xxx, xxx, xxx)  in a stylesheet

Comment: @nipponese: what exactly seems to be the problem? This code should work--you likely have an error elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('*').filter(function(i){  
    return $(this).css("background-color") == $("<div style='color:#d10044'/>").css("color");
}).css("color", "#000")
```

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

You will need to do some normalization on the Hex value, because browsers may report the color as rgba or other format

EDIT: did it for you

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Pvg8h/

Comment: +1 just because you have the exact same amount of rep as I do. =)

Comment: Like this? $('*').filter(function(){
return $(this).css("background-color") == #d10044 || $(this).css("color") == #d10044}).css("background-color", "orange");

Comment: i edited to show you how...just created a new element with that color and let jQuery report what that color was

Comment: I don't get it.. dosomething()? oO

Comment: haha...you don't need that, replace that with whatever you wanted to do with the selection

Comment: @mowgli - You can replace that with your own function.

Comment: ;) I did.. see my comment before. Like that?

Comment: Try it with the fiddle I put up for you, you don't need us to tell you if your code will work, just try it

Comment: It does'nt change the color #d10044, and I don't use inline styles ;)

Comment: there was no error - it just didn't do exactly what you wanted because this site is not a 'can i haz the codes' site. I encourage thinking as opposed to spoonfeeding

Comment: Best way to learn is fixing those things you weren't happy with, with google and jsfiddle as your best friend :)

Comment: The error I did'nt spot first, was that you searched for background-color but replaced the color. But you changed it. Thanx

Comment: Hm I'm still struggling with it. It should change all colors/background-colors from #d10044.. Should I have two filters, one for colors and one for background-colors?

Comment: Yes, except if you want to do it that way, I'd go with Elliot's answer and keep it all in the one function call

Answer (score 0):

You can't select elements based on CSS attribute values with jQuery.

You would have to loop through all the variables individually and check their background color value, then change it if it was #d10044.

Another thing you could do is add a class to the  tag, and then use CSS to override the colors.

Comment: although i admire your epic beard, i disagree...this is what `.filter()` is for. Admittedly it is essentially looping through the objects but it does make it significantly easier